# Cannot detect redirect response in Ajax using Prototype.js in Magento

Tags: ajax, redirect, prototype-js

I'm using Prototype.js to send a post request to a Magento controller. The controller will response a Json data or a redirect e.g. `$this->_redirect('*/*/billing');`
The issue that it seems the Ajax cannot detect the redirect response. I need to "catch" it then handle the redirect action in JavaScript by using `window.location = redirect_url;`
Please help me as I don't want a workaround solution such as modifying response behavior in the controller. Thanks so much!.

```
new Ajax.Request(orderSaveUrl, {
    method: 'post',
    parameters: params,
    onComplete: function (response) {
        window.console.log('success' + response);
    },
    onFailure: function (response) {
        window.console.log('failure' + response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser handles the HTTP redirect internally, but I think you can figure out what the final URL was by inspecting the ajax transport object.

```
new Ajax.Request(orderSaveUrl, {
    method: 'post',
    parameters: params,
    onComplete: function (response) {
        window.console.log('success' + response);
        window.console.log(response.transport.responseURL); // <=====
    },
    onFailure: function (response) {
        window.console.log('failure' + response);
        window.console.log(response.transport.responseURL);
    }
});
```